# xls RC4 encryption password from key

Tags: encryption, rc4

I asked this question on stackoverflow, but thought it may be more appropriate here.

I have a key from a RC4 encrypted excel sheet (xls), along with the salt, and hash, etc. and I have decrypted the file using [this program](https://github.com/GavinSmith0123/crackxls2003).

Is there a way to recover the password that was used from this information?

Comment: Are you asking if the password you used to decrypt the file was the one used by the person who encrypted the file?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich If that is the case, it would be nice.  I am trying to find a way to calculate the password used to encrypt the file if I have a key along with the password salt, etc.  I thought that the key would be different than the password, but perhaps I am wrong?  If the key *is* the password, then I would just have to convert the bits into characters right?  I just didn't think it would be that easy, since there is a password salt.  I apologize if my knowledge of encryption is very lacking.

Comment: According to http://auntitled.blogspot.de/2010/12/excel-rc4-encryption-algorithm.html MD5 is used to derive they key from the password. So there is no easy way to derive the original password and brute-forcing might be the easiest way.